# How to move to one folder back in python

Tags: python, operating-system

Actually need to go some path and execute some command and below is the code

**code**:

```
import os
present_working_directory = '/home/Desktop/folder'
```

presently i am in `folder`

```
if some_condition == true :
    change_path = "nodes/hellofolder"
    os.chdir(change_path)
    print os.getcwd()
if another_condition  == true:
    change_another_path = "nodes" 
    os.chdir(change_another_path) 
    print os.getcwd()

**Result**:
'/home/Desktop/folder/nodes/hellofolder'
python: [Errno 1] No such file or directory
```

Actually whats happening here is when i first used `os.chdir()` the directory has changed to

`'/home/Desktop/folder/nodes/hellofolder'`,

but for the second one i need to run a file by moving to one folder back that is

```
'/home/Desktop/folder/nodes'
```

So can anyone let me how to move one folder back in python

Comment: Avoid `os.chdir` if you can. The `subprocess` module's functions take the working directory as an argument. (Also, `true` should be `True` and `== True` is never necessary.)

Comment: @Kour ipm, as larsmans said, do what you need to do using subprocess, it has the keyword cwd. So call what you need using: subprocess.call("yourCommand", shell=True, cwd="path/to/directory")

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Just like you would in the shell.

```
os.chdir("../nodes")
```

Answer (score 53):

Here is a very platform independent way to do it.

```
In [1]: os.getcwd()
Out[1]: '/Users/user/Dropbox/temp'

In [2]: os.path.normpath(os.getcwd() + os.sep + os.pardir)
Out[2]: '/Users/user/Dropbox/'
```

Then you have the path, and you can chdir or whatever with it.

Comment: what about ''/Users/user/ how can i get it?

Comment: thank you for adding this.it should be the actual answer

Answer (score 35):

Just call

```
os.chdir('..')
```

the same as in any other language :)

Comment: Tried using this and it does not work. Once I try changing using this my path becomes `None`

Answer (score 6):

#### Exact answer for your question is `os.chdir('../')`

#### Use case:

```
Folder1:
    sub-folder1:(you want to navigate here)
Folder2:
    sub-folde2:(you are here)
```

To navigate to `sub-folder1` from `sub-folder2`, you need to write like this
"`../Folder1/sub-folder1/`"

then, put it in `os.chdir("../Folder1/sub-folder1/")`.

Answer (score 2):

think about using absolute paths

```
import os
pwd = '/home/Desktop/folder'

if some_condition == true :
    path = os.path.join(pwd, "nodes/hellofolder")
    os.chdir(path)
    print os.getcwd()
if another_condition  == true:
    path = os.path.join(pwd, "nodes")
    os.chdir(path) 
    print os.getcwd()
```

Answer (score 2):

The answers mentioned above are correct. The following is more of something that usually happens when your Python script is in a nested directory. You want to go one level up from the current working directory to maybe, let's say, load a file.

The idea is to simply reformat the path string and prefix it with a '../'. So an example would be.

```
'../current_directory/' + filename
```

This format is similar to when used in a terminal. Whenever in doubt fire up a terminal and experiment with some commands. The format is reflected in the programming language.

Answer (score 1):

My problem was fixed with this command 
first `import os` and after add
`os.path.normpath(os.path.abspath(__file__) + os.sep + os.pardir)`

Answer (score 0):

Define this function in your script and call it whenever you want to go back just by one folder:

```
import os

def dirback():
    m = os.getcwd()
    n = m.rfind("\\")
    d = m[0: n+1]
    os.chdir(d)
    return None
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
import os
pathX = r'C:/Hello/HelloWorld'
print(os.path.dirname(pathX))
```

Comment: Please explain the effect of what you propose and how it helps to solve the problem. Try for [answer] and consider taking the [tour].