# How to fix json imports two directories up

Tags: python

I am trying to import a config json file from a different directory from where i want to use it. Am getting this error :

**with open('../../config/config.json', 'r') as f:
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '../../config/config.json'**

This is what I did. I tried importing JSON library and load the file as shown in the code below.

```
import json

with open('../../config/config.json', 'r') as f:
config = json.load(f)
```

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: give absolute path not relative path

Answer (score 1):

You need to insert **complete path** to import the file successfully.

The issue is with your **../../config**

Instead give the complete path of the file.

Answer (score 0):

What you're doing *does* work, however isn't great practice and is dependent on other variables for it to work. I'd suggest putting the full (absolute) path of the file you want to read in:

```
with open('the/full/path/to/config/config.json', 'r') as f:
config = json.load(f)
```

Alternatively you can build the path using the `sys` module and assign it to a variable to be used in the `open` call, I'd suggest looking at the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html)

Answer (score 0):

did you try whether that is the correct path? `pathlib.Path` can help you here

```
from pathlib import Path

parent = Path("Path("../../config/"
parent.exists(), parent.is_dir()

p = parent / "config.json"
p.exists()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use pandas to read Json format data.

```
import pandas as pd
pd.read_json('<PATH>')
```

Note Use path like: ././config/config.json
 and call os.chdir('..') before accessing file.

For reference [click here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12280199/5905103)